# How many numbers can a set contain?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Assume that $f: \mathbb R^7 (x_1,...,x_n) \to \mathbb R \in C^4$. 
>   
> How many numbers can a set $\left\{\frac{\partial ^4 f}{\partial x_{i_4}\partial x_{1_3}\partial x_{i_2}\partial x_{i_1}}(0): i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4 \in \left\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \right\} \right\}$contain?

If $f\in C^4$ then the order of partial derivatives doesn't matter.

I thought at first that the solution is $7^4$. But then I count some of the possibilities several times.

I know that the solution is $\binom{7+4-1}{4}$ but I don't understand why it is truth.

Answer (score 1):

That is a typical "[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))" problem. We are looking at the number of ways to write $4$ as a sum of $7$ non-negative integers - each term $i$ in the sum will tell you how many times $\partial x_i$ appears.

For example, the breakdown of $$4=1+0+0+2+0+1+0$$ corresponds to the value $$\frac{\partial^4f}{\partial x_1\partial x_4^2 \partial x_6}$$

Now that is routinely done by placing $4$ stars and $7-1$ bars between them and counting those. For example, the sum above $$4=1+0+0+2+0+1+0$$ can be represented via "stars and bars" as $$*|||**||*|$$ (the terms in the sum correspond to the numbers of stars between consecutive bars, and you have one bar less than the number of terms).

Finally, in how many ways can you arrange $4$ stars and $7-1$ bars? In "$4+7-1$ choose $4$" ways, i.e. ${4+7-1}\choose{4}$

Answer (score 0):

From where are you finding the solution that is given? Unless I am missing something, this is just a counting argument, since a function being $C^4$ means that the order of partial derivatives does not matter, by Clairaut's theorem [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz's_theorem[Theorem%20of%20Schwartz/Clairaut][1]). The way I see it, see if you can figure out first how many ways there are of choosing 4 distinct variables in which to differentiate. Then how many choices you have if you want to do one second partial and two distinct single derivatives. Then two seconds, a third and single, and 4 partials in one variable. This reasoning gives a different answer, though I may be misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I've tried your approach, and it gives ${7\choose 4}=35$ answers with all distinct, $7\cdot{6\choose 2}=105$ with one second partial, ${7\choose 2}=21$ with two seconds, $7\cdot 6=42$ for third+single and $7$ for all four partials, the total is $210={10\choose 4}$ - same result.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I had a typo when calculating the concrete values that made me think the results were different